# Reference Book for Word Progressions

Tags: resources

If a dictionary is a reference book for word definitions, and a thesaurus is a reference book for grouping words according to meaning, what do you call a reference book for **word progressions**?

By *word progressions* I mean such things as:

- Comparatives and superlatives:

  - good/better/best
  - big/bigger/biggest
  - least/less/more/most
- Measures:

  - tiny, small, medium, large, gigantic
  - common/uncommon/rare, unique
  - novice/apprentice/journeyman/master/grandmaster
- Deictic expressions:

  - before/during/after
  - yesterday/today/tomorrow
  - first/second/third/..., first/(then/next)/last
  - penultimate/ultimate

Does such a reference book exist? If not, what are some sources that describe these word progressions?

Comment: I'm certain I don't have all my terminology correct; I'm happy to improve my question quality with helpful comments.

Comment: Between my dictionary and thesaurus, I seem to be covered for all of this.

Comment: @Laurel: My thesaurus will tell me that _before_ has an antonym of _after_ and the dictionary definition of _after_ has the following sentence example: _before, during, and after the war_.  However, none of these individual references correlate the notion of *before/during/after* unless I investigate all three words in two different references, or happen to read the the dictionary entry for _after_ first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a request for resources is off-topic.